# Double click function in jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-click

I have two span elements in a page. when I call a jquery double click function on both then the function is called only on first element. I am using the following code:

```
<span id="shiftTime_1">1</span>
<span id="shiftTime_2">1</span>
```

and jquery function is:

```
 $("[id^='shiftTime_']").dblclick(function() {
 alert("hello");
 });
```

when I double click on the element Id of shiftTime_1. then the function works fine. But when I double click on element Id of shiftTime_2 then this function does not respond.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Seems to be working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Rr2hf/ , try posting your jQuery version or include more code.

Comment: It works fine for me, which jQuery version are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/fCrb5/

Comment: also, check to see if a debugger(ie firebug) shows errors

Comment: Just on one browser or on all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use inside `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("[id^='shiftTime_']").dblclick(function() {
 alert("hello");
 });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you plan to add elements dynamically (e.g. by using `$( "body" ).append( "<span id='shiftTime_2'>1</span>" );` )

```
$( "body" ).on( "dblclick", "span", function() {
    alert( "This works also with dynamically added elements" );
} );
```

Comment: Great! You save my time! happy coding

Comment: Cheers. I would like to add that in 2018 it might be bad for the user experience to request a double-click (A lot of your users might want to use a touchscreen where there is no double-click).

Answer (score 1):

When I try the code, it works just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/pfQfK/

Check if there is something different from your code.