# Jquery double click event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

My requirement is to just double click a button.

HTML:

```
 <button id="btn-db" class="dbBtn" ></button>
```

Solutions tried:

```
  $("#btn-id").trigger("dblclick");
```

is not triggering double click event

Note: I've tried the same thing for single click,

```
  $("#btn-id").trigger("click");
```

Single click is triggering by invoking above statement in browsers console.

Comment: this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680290/double-click-function-in-jquery-is-not-working

Comment: Did you try  `.dblclick(...)`?

Comment: No. Give a example of to how to use it

Comment: @Chintan let me check

Answer (score 1):

Try `button.on("dblclick", ...)`. Here is an example.

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("dblclick", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Such a giant example for such a simple problem… :p

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```js
$("#btn-id").on('dblclick', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log("You double-clicked!");
});

$("#btn-id").trigger("dblclick");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-id" class="dbBtn">Double click</button>
```

I just noticed this is a typo error:
`<button id="btn-db" class="dbBtn" ></button>`: id should be `btn-id` in your code!

Hope it helps.